# Having problems getting variable into javascript generated input

Tags: javascript, escaping

So I'm trying to generate an input form using Javascript so that I can add multiple lines of the same input boxes.

```
var color_form = document.getElementById('color_form');
var create = document.createElement('input');
create.setAttribute('method', 'post');
create.setAttribute('name', "\"red[" + i + "]");
create.setAttribute('class', 'color_entry');
create.setAttribute('placeholder', 'red');
color_form.appendChild(create); //Append red value to color_form
```

I've tried adding another ending quote and leaving it off but sometimes it will just omit the form altogether and sometimes it gives me this

```
<input class="color_entry" method="post" name=""red[" + i + "]"" placeholder="red"></input>
```

Can anybody point me to what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create.setAttribute('name', "\"red[" + i + "]");
```

should be

```
create.setAttribute('name', "red[" + i + "]");
```

No need to escape.

Comment: This is all setup using MAMP. So i'm not sure where the javascript errors are logged to.

Comment: Update: found logs. it's complaining about character encoding. Trying to work that out real quick.

Comment: So upon investigation when I set a reset function, I had moved the "i" variable from being a global value to a function specific value.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're escaping quotes in the `name` attribute:

```
create.setAttribute('name', "red[" + i + "]");
```